# Re-install Google Play after it was removed / uninstalled

Tags: google-play-store, 4.2-jelly-bean

I have deleted Google Play from my HTC One X Plus. I have also deleted Google Play from `system/app`. After that, I re-installed it, but it didn't work. Whenever I ppb it, it says Google play stoped working.

How do I re-install Google Play? My device is rooted.

Answer (score 1):

Re-flashing the GApps package fitting for your Android version should fix it. You can find them [at goo.im](http://goo.im/gapps). Make sure the archive you pick is for your Android version; according to the tag you've used, it should be `gapps-jb-*`.